# Could not initialize class KinesisClientLibConfiguration while integrating kinesis consumer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, producer-consumer, amazon-kcl, amazon-kinesis-kpl

I am integrating kinesis in my java springboot project, i am able to publish the data into kinesis stream but while consuming it i am getting error like below :

```
Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisClientLibConfiguration
```

Error coming on below line exactly :

```
KinesisClientLibConfiguration kinesisClientLibConfiguration = null;
         kinesisClientLibConfiguration = new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(applicationName, streamName, credentialsProvider, workerId);
```

I am using below version for integration in my pom.xml :

com.amazonaws(sdk) : 1.11.980
and kcl (amazon-kinesis-client) version : 1.9.0

I got to know KinesisClientLibConfiguration is deprecated in 1.9.0 so i used 1.14.2 as well but issue is still the same.

Can someone please help me on this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but to find out what is causing the issue, run your jar file in EC2 machine within its file location 'java -jar package.jar'

In my case, my jar was created with higher java version but in EC2 it was lower version.